# Check if element contains another

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I have this code:

```
$('#detail div p').each(function() {
 if ($(this).children("i").length) {
     var TheVar = "Yes";
     MyData.push(TheVar);
 } else {
     var TheVar = "No";
     MyData.push(TheVar);
 };
});
```

The problem is that I sometimes get an incorrect answer, because if the `i` element inside `p` is not yet loaded, then I get `No` instead of `Yes`. Is there any solution to wait until the dom is loaded?

Best Regards

Comment: Is this code inside a `$(document).ready(function() {` wrapper?

Comment: If these children are loaded through ajax then the only way to do "counting" is to do it in the success method of the ajax call.

Comment: This code is inside  `request` module in node, `var $ = cheerio.load(body);`

Comment: set a delay ... if dom is loaded async there is no way to know when that is done. SHould also tag this as cheerio

Comment: @charlietfl Ok, only solution? Example? Post it and I accept:)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running this in cheerio and have no control over any asynchronous data loading, try setting a 5 second delay (or longer)

```
setTimeout(function(){
   // try now

},5000);
```

You could also use an interval timer to check if certain elements exist and when they do cancel the interval timer

Comment: Ok, that sounds great. Please update your answer to set such a cancel?

Comment: to look for what? Not hard to use `setInterval` and `clearInterval`

Comment: To look for if `i` exists:)

Comment: same concept..check it's length

Comment: Yes, but there are several `$('#detail div p')`, some do contain `i` (but loads after a few seconds) some do not.

Comment: then it doesn't sound like that's what you want to look for in an interval check. What I meant was maybe there are other elements that show up at the very end for example